# Find 3th triangle coordinate when two coords the length of two sides and an angle is given

Tags: triangles

Hello mathematicians 
A friend and I tried to figure this out for a while. We tried a lot, but could not find anything.

We have two given points (A and B)
Two given lengths ($\overline{AB}$ = $\overline{BC}$)
One given corner ($\alpha$)

We want to find a general formula for the coordinates of C.

We basicly want the formula to be valid for any angle, with any coordinates, with any length.

I hope someone can help us out, we think we are looking over something.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Essentially, you need to rotate the segment $AB$ through an angle of $\alpha$. There are many resources that explain how to do this that you can find with a quick web search.

Comment: Thanks, this was the information I was looking for! (I'll check out the links you gave me too)

Answer (score 0):

Since is a isosceles triangle, and $AB = BC$, you know that $By = Cy$. Because $AB$ 
and $BC$ have the same length. If you cut the Triangle in two parts you can see 
that it forms two right triangle.

Now, how to find $Cx$. Well $|Cx - Bx| = BC$  Becausa in a plane, the distance between two points (In the same axis, this case, x) $A$ and $B$ is $|A - B|$ which is the same that $|B - A|$